# WooCommerce purchase redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my WooCommerce site, after someone makes a purchase, the page simply refeshes and appends this URL

`/order-received/1947/?key=wc_order_58eab080068de`

I have researched the `order-received` tag but even after reading the documents about [endpoints](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/) I still have 0 idea what this is supposed to do, and why it is not doing it.

In my WooCommerce settings I have the setting for Registration set to go to a confirmation page, but this also does not seem to apply.

How can I stop the page from simply refreshing and get it to go to the purchase confirmation page?

Comment: No custom code. Guest checkout is not enabled, this is a subscription that signs you up after purchase. Enable registration on the Checkout Page is enabled. Can you possibly explain what endpoints are supposed to accomplish? Nowhere in WooCommerce docs does it describe what this link is actually supposed to do, just that it's "better than last version"

Comment: This link is about "the thank you page" (or "Order received page") that happen just after checkout after the payment. It shows to the customer what is the result of his payment and recaps the order. This is part of normal woocommerce process.

Comment: I see - so what is my issue if the page simply refreshes? It does not show the thank you page or order received. All of my customers think their order has failed, because the page just refreshes after successful purchase. Note: This is a WooCommerce One Page Checkout

Comment: Checkout pages and Order received page are very different… so may be there is a problem due to your customizations (I mean 1 page checkout) or may be your theme or a plugin

Comment: ok.. i see. this is a catastrophe.. how wordpress/wordcommerce are 10 year old products blows my mind - they barely work.